# Beginner SAS and SAS2 speed expectations

Tags: sas, sata

We have one SAS backplane, without SAS expander, with 8 HDDs and we connect it to the motherboard with 2 SFF-8087 to 4 sas/sata cables.

The motherboard supports SAS2 and the SSD supports SAS2. How fast will my SSD be, 300MB/S or 600MB/S?

Comment: In theory the maximum bandwidth is 768MB/sec for a 6 Gbps SAS-2 connection. But there are not many SSD's that can actually push that much data from a single drive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! If my backplane is only sas1, will i get sas2 speeds from this configuration?

Comment: Obviously not. If the backplane is SAS 1 - it will use SAS 1. That said - if that is a 8 port Supermicro 8x2.5" in 2x5.25" - IT WILL NOT WORK ;) The chip there is not SAS 2 compatible. Found that out the hard way ;)

Comment: If i use 4 of the 8 hdds, will those 4get 600mbs speed? (do you have an alternative if not)

Comment: please anyone???

Comment: Wind64bit, you seem to be posting a number of highly-hardware-specific questions this morning.  You got lucky above; TomTom is an experienced member of this site, and has used the exact piece of equipment you're asking about.  But **the best person to ask about the exact functionality of a specific piece of equipment is the manufacturer** - not only do they know it better than just about anyone, their answer is often binding in a way that opinions on a web QA site are not.

Answer (score 1):

This is a function of your backplane's capacity, but assuming it is 6Gbps SAS compatible, your SSD should be capable of establishing a 6Gbps link.